# facebook profile image using Email id?

Tags: php, facebook

i want to show a facebook profile image only by using email id... 
i have done this with user id , but i need to display using email id....

/** Below working code with user ID but I need it with email ID **/

```
<?php 
    $t  = "11"; 
    if(isset($_POST['email_id'])) 
    { 
         $t=$_POST['email_id'];     
    } 
?> 

<form name="sample_form" action="" method="post"> 
    <table> 
    <tr> 
        <td></td> 
        <td>
            <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/&lt;?php echo $t; ?>/picture?type=large" alt="" />
        <td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Username / User ID :</td> 
        <td> 
            <input type="text" value="" name="email_id" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Find FB profile image" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

can anyone know how spokeo.com work  
it can featch facebook profile image using email id 
 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without asking for the user's permission.

However, if you have a valid access token I believe this endpoint may do what you're looking for:
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={EMAIL}&type=user`

Comment: Two comments: 1) It is possible to search for any other user by their email so long as you are using a **user** `access_token` and the email owner's profile is visible to that user. 2) Add `&fields=picture` to the above url to get the picture returned with the request.

Comment: Thanks , I had also tryed with above code .
but know how spokeo.com work  ??
it is featch image using email id

Comment: Presumably spokeo gets the data from accounts configured for full public access. I did a search for a friend of mine in the US with a private account and it had never heard of them.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible after 2011 because after that email can be made private by the user so you can't fetch the data with the help of email id.**